# Binding Date to DatePicker - Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, datepicker, windows-phone-8.1

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        datepicker.DataContext = e.Parameter;
        time.DataContext = e.Parameter;
    }

    <DatePicker Name="datepicker" Header="Date" Date="{Binding Date}"/>
    <TimePicker Name="time" Header="Time" Time="{Binding Time}"/>
```

I have a listbox of entries of type Reminder on a page. I select one of the items and navigate to the next page,  passing the ListBox.SelectedItem. I want to be able to bind the date passed from the previous page to the DatePicker on the current page. I am able to bind the time to the TimePicker, but not the date to the DatePicker.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: Please show your work as a text, not image.

Comment: @Soner - Edited to show code as text instead of image.

Comment: Are you talking about [Reminder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/office/office365/microsoft.phone.scheduler.reminder(v=vs.105).aspx) class? Or is it some custom class you have created?

Comment: It is a custom class I have created called Reminder

Comment: I'm guessing your `Date` property is of type `DateTime`. On the other hand, the `DatePicker.Date` property is of type `DateTimeOffset`. So you'll probably need to convert it to `DateTimeOffset` type. I could be more sure if I could take a look at your `Reminder` class.

Comment: @Abhishek - That's what the problem was. Converted to DateTimeOffset and now it is working correctly. Thank you :)

Comment: Oops! Should've put it as an answer :D Anyways glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Converted Date to DateTimeOffset and now it works correctly.